# Bone local coordinate adjustment

Tags: rigging, constraints

I have a small rig setup on which I am working. Later in pose mode I want the root bone to affect several (IK) bones. To have a better control I want to do it with contraints. So, lets say when I move the root bone in pose mode I want that another bones is moved also like the root bone is the parent. The problem is, that the local axis of the root bone and the other bone are different and when I setup the Copy Location Constraint (with local space <-> local space) and move the root one the affect is wrong, cause the target bone is moved on the wrong axis. I tried to correct the local axis of the target to make it the same like the root bone. For this, I used the recalculate roll tools in the armature menu, but I can only correct one axis. Any advice, how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align bones in **Edit Mode** select the bone you want to align and then the bone you want to copy the alignment from. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> (Align Bones).

As a side note: If you need them to have different rotations, parent them on additional bones and use the copy location constraint on the parents instead. That way you can rotate the childs freely without worrying about their translation.

An easier solution might be to use **Pose Space** to **Pose Space** for the copy location constraint and tick on **Offset** in the constraints panel.